# Right-to-left languages as Abstracts on IEEE article

Tags: packages, babel, languages, ieeetran, article

fellows.
My concern is about getting different languages in an IEEE document, the following code is working, but I need to get Arabic and Hebrew abstracts too, the issue is getting appropriate packages to get the right-to-left languages. Any other left-to-right language such as Russian, Greek or Esperanto can be handled by me.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\title{Taller de simulación II}
\author{
Diego Nicolás Peña$^\dag$,\thanks{$^\dag$ Cód.: 223537 (correo electrónico: \textit{dnpenaa@unal.edu.co}).}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\begin{abstract}
En el presente documento se expone una solución a cada uno de los ejercicios propuestos por el director de clase mediante un desarrollo analítico y una correspondiente comprobación por medio de simulación con el software OrCAD\textregistered \space Capture CIS. El tema a plantear en este ejercicio es el análisis de respuesta completa en circuitos RL y RC.
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
Herein a solution for each excercise proposed by the head of class is exposed, this through analytical development and hence a verification by using the OrCAD\textregistered \space Capture CIS simulation software. The analysis addresses complete response of RL and RC circuits issues.
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumo}
\begin{abstract}
Neste documento apresenta-se uma solução aos excercícios propostos pelo instrutor de aula mediante um desenvolvimento analítico e uma consequente avaliação por intermédio de simulação com o software OrCAD\textregistered \space Capture CIS. O tema exposto aqui é a resposta completa de circuitos RL e RC.
\end{abstract}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
{\small \textbf{
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
摘要\textemdash 这里的班主任提出的每一个练习的解决方法都被展现了，通过分析发展和利用 OrCAD\textregistered \space Capture CIS仿真软件的验证，讨论出了关于RL和RC电路的完整解答。
\end{CJK*}
}}
\vspace{2mm}\\
\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Palabras clave}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
simulación, circuito, teoremas, comprobación.\nolinebreak
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Index Terms}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
simulation, circuit, theorems, substantiation.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Palavras-chave}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
simulação, circuito, teoremas, comprovação.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
{\small \textbf{关键词\textemdash 仿真、电路、定理、测试。}}
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Okay. I managed to use XeTeX to perform what I wanted.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\title{El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz cardillo y kiwi}
\author{El Ovaldo, loco.}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
%Linux Libertine O
\newfontfamily\arabicfontA
    [Script=Arabic, Scale=1]
    {Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\textarabic}[1] 
         {
         \bgroup\luatextextdir \arabicfontA #1\egroup
         }

\newcommand{\n}     [1]
     {\bgroup\luatextextdir #1\egroup}
\newenvironment{Arabic}
      {
        \luatextextdir \luatexpardir \arabicfontA
      }{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
En el presente documento se expone una solución a cada uno de los ejercicios propuestos por el director de clase mediante un desarrollo analítico y una correspondiente comprobación por medio de simulación con el software OrCAD\textregistered~Capture~CIS. El tema a plantear en este ejercicio es el análisis de respuesta completa en circuitos RL y RC.
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
Herein a solution for each exercise proposed by the head of class is exposed, this through analytical development and hence a verification by using the OrCAD\textregistered~Capture~CIS simulation software. The analysis addresses complete response of RL and RC circuits issues.
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumo}
\begin{abstract}
Neste documento apresenta-se uma solução aos excercícios propostos pelo instrutor de aula mediante um desenvolvimento analítico e uma consequente avaliação por intermédio de simulação com o software OrCAD\textregistered \space Capture CIS. O tema exposto aqui é a resposta completa de circuitos RL e RC.
\end{abstract}
\begin{abstract}
Neste documento apresenta-se uma solução aos excercícios propostos pelo instrutor de aula mediante um desenvolvimento analítico e uma consequente avaliação por intermédio de simulação com o software OrCAD\textregistered \space Capture CIS. O tema exposto aqui é a resposta completa de circuitos RL e RC.
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{摘要}
\begin{abstract}
这里的班主任提出的每一个练习的解决方法都被展现了，通过分析发展和利用 OrCAD\textregistered~Capture~CIS仿真软件的验证，讨论出了关于RL和RC电路的完整解答。
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{תקציר}
\begin{hebrew}
\begin{abstract}

זהו פתרון עבור כל אחד מהתרגילים שניתנו על ידי ראש המחלקה, באמצעות פיתוח אנליטי.
הפתרון אומת באמצעות תוכנת \LR{OrCAD®~PSpice~CIS}. הניתוח מתייחס לתגובה מלאה במעגלי RL וRC.
\end{abstract}

\textbf{\textarabic{
محاذاةإلى \textemdash اليمين \LR{OrCAD®~PSpice~CIS}.
}}
\end{hebrew}

\vspace{1mm}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Русский}
\begin{abstract}
Все люди рождаются свободными и равными в своем достоинстве и правах.
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Ελληνικά}
\begin{abstract}
Ὅλοι οἱ ἄνθρωποι γεννιοῦνται ἐλεύθεροι καὶ ἴσοι στὴν ἀξιοπρέπεια 
καὶ τὰ δικαιώματα.
\end{abstract}
English text
``\textarabic{جملة عربية وسط جملة إنجليزية}''
with Arabic in
between. Or again in a different font: 
\textarabic{
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين \n{١٢٣٤٥} فقرة عربية
محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى
\\
اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين.
}

\section{Unicode support}

\subsection{English}
All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights.

\subsection{Íslenska}
Hver maður er borinn frjáls og jafn öðrum að virðingu og réttindum.



\subsection{Tiếng Việt}
Tất cả mọi người sinh ra đều được tự do và bình đẳng về nhân phẩm và 
quyền lợi.
\section{Legacy syntax}
When he goes---``Hello World!''\\
She replies—“Hello dear!”

\section{Ligatures}
\fontspec[Ligatures={Common, Historical}]{Linux Libertine O}
\fontsize{10pt}{18pt}\selectfont Questo è strano assai ectoti Affiris, \textit{Difficult} flauta, intrínseco, Afflaunted. aftudisíaco.

\section{Numerals}
\fontspec[Numbers={OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O}Old style: 1234567\\
\fontspec[Numbers={Lining}]{Linux Libertine O}Lining: 1234567
\begin{equation*}
x = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I had to arrange some things that create a couple of errors I have not been able to fix but I can bear them. Hope it works for someone. @penguinpreferred.

Comment: Your MWE seems to have a lot of extra packages loaded and there seems to be no RTL languages in the sample text. Having a 'minimal' example simplifies troubleshooting, as does an example which actually shows the difficulty.

Comment: @penguinpreferred okay, I deleted not necessary packages for this example. I hope you can help me, I DO NOT KNOW how to place right-to-left languages here, not a clue about it.

Comment: @penguinpreferred Alright, I can write some short:
שפן אכל קצת גזר בטעם חסה, ודי
and
لا أتكلم العربية
but I do not know how to place them in the abstract.

Comment: does the MWE compile for you? I get an error: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc`. Further, if you don't know the languages you want to use, how do you know what to insert? If you have some text to copy in, please indicate in the document where you want it.

Comment: Below the Chinese abstract I want:
Hebrew: שפן אכל קצת גזר בטעם חסה, ודי
Arabic:لا أتكلم العربية

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use XeTeX (or similar), which allows direct use of unicode and system fonts. The example below uses Times New Roman for the main font, and specifies two others for the Chinese and Hebrew (WenQuanYi Micro Hei and Cardo, respectively). You can change the fonts to the appropriate type faces on your system.

Unfortunately, I have stopped using plain latex for multilingual work years ago, so I cannot give a good solution based on plain tex.

Doing it this way, you only need to insert the text between the appropriate `\begin` and `\end` commands, and add any necessary font switching if the main font does not have the necessary characters.

```
\documentclass[hebrew,spanish]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}

\newfontfamily\cjkfont{WenQuanYi Micro Hei}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Cardo}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}

\title{Taller de simulación II}


\author{Diego Nicolás Peña$^{\dag}$%
\thanks{$^{\dag}$ Cód.: 223537 (correo electrónico: \textit{dnpenaa@unal.edu.co}).%
} }
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
En el presente documento se expone una solución a cada uno de los
ejercicios propuestos por el director de clase mediante un desarrollo
analítico y una correspondiente comprobación por medio de simulación
con el software OrCAD®\ Capture CIS. El tema a plantear en este ejercicio
es el análisis de respuesta completa en circuitos RL y RC. 
\end{abstract}

\global\long\def\abstractname{Abstract}

\begin{abstract}
Herein a solution for each excercise proposed by the head of class
is exposed, this through analytical development and hence a verification
by using the OrCAD®\ Capture CIS simulation software. The analysis
addresses complete response of RL and RC circuits issues. 
\end{abstract}

\global\long\def\abstractname{Resumo}

\begin{abstract}
Neste documento apresenta-se uma solução aos excercícios propostos
pelo instrutor de aula mediante um desenvolvimento analítico e uma
consequente avaliação por intermédio de simulação com o software OrCAD®\ Capture
CIS. O tema exposto aqui é a resposta completa de circuitos RL e RC. 

{\cjkfont 摘要—这里的班主任提出的每一个练习的解决方法都被展现了，通过分析发展和利用 OrCAD®\ Capture CIS仿真软件的验证，讨论出了关于RL和RC电路的完整解答。 }
\end{abstract}

\global\long\def\abstractname{ResumoHeb}

\begin{hebrew}%
\begin{abstract}
שפן אכל קצת גזר בטעם חסה, ודי
\end{abstract}

\end{hebrew}%
\vspace{2mm}


\global\long\def\IEEEkeywordsname{Palabras clave}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
simulación, circuito, teoremas, comprobación.\nolinebreak 
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\global\long\def\IEEEkeywordsname{Index Terms}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
simulation, circuit, theorems, substantiation. 
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\global\long\def\IEEEkeywordsname{Palavras-chave}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
simulação, circuito, teoremas, comprovação. 

{\cjkfont 关键词—仿真、电路、定理、测试。}\end{IEEEkeywords}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have managed a way to place all the languages I wanted with XeTeX, it looks so amazing. I will place my own working code to let it know the world. :) @penguinpreferred.

Comment: You're welcome. The best way to give thanks is to accept an answer or up-vote a comment.